# UICollectionViewCell size wrong when using Kingfisher activityIndicator

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, kingfisher

I've got a collectionview that is loading images from URLs via the kingfisher library. I'm trying to achieve a 3 column layout and this is working fine, until I add a loadingIndicator via kingfisher.

My cellForRowAt method is as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let item = mediaItems!.data![indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PictureCell", for: indexPath) as! PictureCell
        let url = URL(string:item.mediaURL!)!
        cell.thumbNail.kf.setImage(with:url)
        //cell.thumbNail.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        return cell

    }
```

If I uncomment the `indicatorType` line the it shrinks all cells to the size of the indicator.

I use the following in my flowLayoutDelegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let yourWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width/3.0) - 3
           let yourHeight = yourWidth

           return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }
```

My size delegate method is called and is returning the correct size, but when displayed the items are all shrunk putting more than 3 items per row (they look to be the default size of 50 width wise). The collectionView has constraints pinning it to the superview as well.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: can you share project via wetranser ?

Comment: I can’t unfortunately, but there isn’t much else to provide in the context of this collection view though

Comment: okay .. thank you ....